# Mongoose validation CastError: Cast to string failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, web-development-server

I am trying to run my .js script in node but while adding some new data in database the server is not loading and giving this error(CastError: Cast to string failed for value). I am not getting the error can someone please help me out?Attaching the SS of cmd and the code as well![enter image description here][1]

```
Code is as follows:


var express=require("express");
var app= express();
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser",  true);
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology",true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/yelp_camp");

var campgroundsschema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String
});

var Campground= mongoose.model("Campground",campgroundsschema);


//Campground.create(
  //  {
    //  name:"Granite Hill",
      //image:"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487750404521-0bc4682c48c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
    //},function(err,campgrounds){
      //if(err){
       //   console.log(err);
      //}
      //else{
       //   console.log("We have created a new campground");
        //  console.log(campgrounds);
      //}
    //}
    //)


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("landing");
});


app.get("/campgrounds",function(req,res){
     
     Campground.find({},function(err,allCampgrounds){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("campgrounds",{campgrounds:allCampgrounds});
        }
     });
});

app.post("/campgrounds",function(req,res){
  var name=req.body.name;
  var image=req.body.image;
  var newCampground={name: name,image: image};
  Campground.create(newCampground,function(err,newlyCreated){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("we have created a new campground here!!");
          res.redirect("/campgrounds");
        }
  });
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new",function(req,res){
     res.render("newcamp.ejs");

 });


var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
});


Error ScreenShot:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vNPz.png
```

( please open this link to view the image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the image link that you attached in the body. I can see that you are sending an array of string which apparently looks like this

`[ "C1", "A URL" ]`

which is actually an array data type, whereas the type that you have set in your schema for name is **String**.

If you want to save an array of strings? You must change the data type to Array of strings i.e.

`name: [String]`

or you can stringify the array that you are sending. Using

`JSON.stringify(yourArray)`

[This](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) is the url to  data types of mongoose so you can explore other data types as well.

**UPDATE**

`var image = JSON.stringify(req.body.image);`

In the above chunk of code i stringified the array of images. And then I tried to save it and its working.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help! I tried to do this but still the error is persisting

Comment: @SOHAMBHAT did you try stringify the array that you are trying to save?

Because I just did it on my side and it is working. You can implement an array data type. And if you want to store the array in strings? Then you should stringify the array.

Comment: Yes I changed the data type to Array and I stringfied the array as well ,now the code is running but I want to display the name and image on my html page that is not happening!!Thankyou for your response

Comment: Thankyou so much error is resolved by changing the data type and strigifying the array of images!!!

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Can you accept the answer as the correct one now?